# Getting short path in python

Tags: python, windows, path, filenames

How do I obtain the short path of a file in Windows using python ?

I am using the following code ,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
fileList = []
rootdir = sys.argv[1]
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        fileList.append(os.path.join(root,file))
for File in fileList:
    print File
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__GetShortPathName_meth.html

Although you will need the win32api module for this.

Also see this link:
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-May/004697.html

Comment: Solution without win32api: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23598461/2441026

Answer (score 2):

```
import win32api
long_file_name='C:\Program Files\I am a file'
short_file_name=win32api.GetShortPathName(long_file_name)
```