# creating scheduled tasks using python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have problem with creating scheduled tasks with python. After executing my command, scheduled task's action part splits into argument and path slices and makes it invalid. I have tried lots of ways like "\" mypath \"" but was not successful.
How can I concatenate executable's path to variable that makes scheduled task's task action valid ?

[image: IMG-1: After creating scheduled task using script. Action path is invalid.]

```
import os
import subprocess


path = os.environ['APPDATA']
filename = "test.exe"
path = path+"\\"+filename

command = 'schtasks.exe /CREATE /RU "%USERNAME%" /SC ONLOGON /TN "testServiceHello" /TR "'+path+'"'


proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout_value = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
print stdout_value
print "--"*50
print command
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the command line sounds OK, you should rely on parameter list, not parameter as string. Let `popen` do the heavy lifting and quote your parameters properly instead of trying to do it yourself.

I'd rewrite that as follows (and would drop `shell=True`, and merge the stdout+stderr from `subprocess.Popen` directly to avoid potential deadlocks)

```
command = ['schtasks.exe','/CREATE','/RU',os.getenv("USERNAME"),'/SC','ONLOGON','/TN','testServiceHello','/TR',os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"test.exe")]
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout_value = proc.stdout.read()
```

you can print what `subprocess` will issue as a command like this:

```
subprocess.list2cmdline(command)
```

In your case, you have an extra problem because there seems to be a limitation in `schtasks.exe`. So the workaround would be to compute windows short path (lifted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598289/how-to-get-windows-short-file-name-in-python))

```
import win32api
long_file_name=os.path.join(os.environ['APPDATA'],"test.exe")
short_file_name=win32api.GetShortPathName(long_file_name)
command = ['schtasks.exe','/CREATE','/RU',os.getenv("USERNAME"),'/SC','ONLOGON','/TN','testServiceHello','/TR',short_file_name]
```

and go on with the `subprocess` call