# Trying to delete file with python but I'm getting WinError 32 Permission Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I've got a pretty weird problem that was really hard to replicate.  I'm playing sounds with a few different libraries depending on the file type.  I want to be able to delete the sound so I clear the audio player (by reassigning the audio_player variable) before removing the file with os.remove(), that's when I get the permission error, but only when the audio player I cleared was using pygame. I havn't got a clue why this is happening but I've been able to consistently replicate it in a test file, here's both that file and the original one, It's got something to do with the SoundPlayer.reload_sound_from_different_file()

**Original aka AudioPlayer**

```py
import pygame
import MetaData
import os
import time
from random import random
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSlot


class PlaysoundException(Exception):
    pass


class SoundSigs(QObject):
    time_changed = pyqtSignal()
    set_current_time = pyqtSignal(float)
    reset_cursor = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(str)


class SoundPlayer(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SoundPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.path = ''
        self.signals = SoundSigs()
        self.wav_list = ['.wav']
        self.pygame_list = ['.flac', '.ogg', '.mp3']
        self.current_result = ''
        self.pixel_time_conversion_rate = 0
        self.audio_player = AudioPlayer()

    def reset(self):
        self.audio_player.stop()
        self.audio_player = AudioPlayerPlaceholder()

    def space_bar(self):
        if self.audio_player.ended:
            self.audio_player.goto(0)
        elif self.audio_player.playing:
            self.audio_player.pause()
        else:
            self.audio_player.resume()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.audio_player.playing and not self.audio_player.ended and not \
                    self.audio_player.passed_download_head:
                time.sleep(.003)
                self.signals.time_changed.emit()
            time.sleep(.01)

    def load(self, path, pixel_time_conversion_rate):
        self.pixel_time_conversion_rate = pixel_time_conversion_rate
        self.audio_player = self.get_correct_audio_player(path)
        self.audio_player.load(path)

    def get_correct_audio_player(self, path):
        file_type = os.path.splitext(path)[1].lower()
        if file_type in self.wav_list:
            return WavPlayer()
        elif file_type in self.pygame_list:
            return PygamePlayer()

    def load_segment(self, path, true_duration, pixel_time_conversion_rate):
        current_time = self.audio_player.current_time
        playing = self.audio_player.playing
        self.audio_player.stop()
        self.audio_player = self.get_correct_audio_player(path)
        self.pixel_time_conversion_rate = pixel_time_conversion_rate
        self.audio_player.load_segment(path, true_duration)
        self.audio_player.goto(current_time)
        if playing:
            self.audio_player.play()

    def preload(self, true_duration, pixel_time_conversion_rate):
        self.audio_player.stop()
        self.signals.time_changed.emit()
        self.audio_player = AudioPlayerPlaceholder()
        self.pixel_time_conversion_rate = pixel_time_conversion_rate
        self.audio_player.preload(true_duration)
        self.audio_player.play()

    def reload_sound_from_different_file(self, path):
        current_time = self.audio_player.current_time
        playing = self.audio_player.playing
        self.audio_player.stop()
        self.audio_player = self.get_correct_audio_player(path)
        self.audio_player.load(path)
        self.audio_player.goto(current_time)
        if playing:
            self.audio_player.play()

    @staticmethod
    def calculate_px_time_conversion_rate(waveform_width, sound_duration):
        return waveform_width/sound_duration

    def goto(self, position):
        self.audio_player.goto(position/self.pixel_time_conversion_rate)
        self.signals.time_changed.emit()


class AudioPlayerSigs(QObject):
    error = pyqtSignal(str)


class AudioPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.signals = AudioPlayerSigs()
        self.loaded = False
        self._playing = False
        self.loop = False
        self.segment = False
        self._path = ''
        self.path = ''
        self._original_path = ''
        self._meta_data = None
        self._duration = 0
        self.attempted_current_time = 0
        self.passed_download_head = False
        self._current_time_start = 0
        self.current_time_stop = 0
        self._current_time_stop = 0
        self._current_time = 0
        self.current_time = 0

    def __del__(self):
        self._meta_data = None

    @property
    def current_time_stop(self):
        if not self.playing:
            return self._current_time_stop
        return time.time()

    @current_time_stop.setter
    def current_time_stop(self, value):
        self._current_time_stop = value

    @property
    def playing(self):
        return self._playing

    @playing.setter
    def playing(self, value):
        if value:
            self._current_time_start = time.time()
        else:
            self._current_time = self.current_time
            self.current_time_stop = time.time()
            self._current_time_start = time.time()
        self._playing = value

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @path.setter
    def path(self, value):
        self._original_path = value
        self._path = get_short_path_name(value)

    @property
    def current_time(self) -> int:
        if self.playing:
            return int((self.current_time_stop - self._current_time_start)*1000) + self._current_time
        return self._current_time

    @current_time.setter
    def current_time(self, value):
        self._current_time_start = time.time()
        self._current_time = value

    @property
    def meta_data(self):
        if self.loaded:
            return self._meta_data
        self._meta_data = self.get_meta_file()
        return self._meta_data

    @property
    def true_duration(self):
        return self.meta_data['duration']

    @property
    def duration(self):
        if self.segment:
            return self._duration
        return self.true_duration

    @property
    def ended(self):
        return self.duration <= self.current_time

    def get_meta_file(self):
        return MetaData.get_meta_file(self._original_path)

    def load(self, path):
        self.path = path

        self._meta_data = self.get_meta_file()
        self.loaded = True
        self._load(self.path)

    def _load(self, path):
        pass

    def reload(self, path, playing):
        self.path = path
        self._meta_data = self.get_meta_file()
        self.stop()
        self._reload(path)
        self.loaded = True
        if playing:
            self.play()

    def _reload(self, path):
        pass

    def play(self):
        if not self.playing:
            self.playing = True
            self._play()

    def _play(self):
        pass

    def pause(self):
        if self.playing:
            self.playing = False
            self._pause()

    def _pause(self):
        pass

    def resume(self):
        if not self.playing:
            self.playing = True
            self._resume()

    def _resume(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        if self.loaded:
            self._reset()
            self._stop()

    def _stop(self):
        pass

    def goto(self, position):
        self.current_time = position
        if self.segment and position >= self.true_duration:
            self.pause()
            self.attempted_current_time = position
            self.passed_download_head = True
        else:
            self._goto(position)
        if not self.playing:
            self._pause()

    def _goto(self, position):
        pass

    def _reset(self):
        self.loaded = False
        self.playing = False
        self.loop = False
        self.segment = False
        self.passed_download_head = False
        self.current_time = 0

    def end(self):
        if self.loop:
            self.goto(0)
            self.play()

    def swap_file_with_complete_file(self, path):
        if self.passed_download_head:
            current_time = self.attempted_current_time
        else:
            current_time = self.current_time
        playing = self.playing
        self.stop()
        self.reload(path, playing)
        self.goto(current_time)

    load_rest_of_segment = swap_file_with_complete_file

    def swap_file_with_incomplete_file(self, path, duration):
        current_time = self.current_time
        self.stop()
        self.load_segment(path, duration)
        self.goto(current_time)
        self.play()

    def load_segment(self, path, duration):
        self.segment = True
        self._duration = duration
        self.load(path)


class WavPlayer(AudioPlayer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WavPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.alias = ''

    def __del__(self):
        self.win_command('close', self.alias)

    def _load(self, path):
        self.alias = 'playsound_' + str(random())
        self.win_command('open "' + self.path + '" alias', self.alias)
        self.win_command('set', self.alias, 'time format milliseconds')

    def _reload(self, path):
        self._load(path)

    def _play(self):
        self.win_command('play', self.alias, 'from', str(round(self.current_time)), 'to', str(self.duration))

    def _pause(self):
        self.win_command('pause', self.alias)

    def _resume(self):
        self.win_command('play', self.alias)

    def _stop(self):
        self.win_command('stop', self.alias)

    def _goto(self, position):
        self.win_command('play', self.alias, 'from', str(round(position)), 'to', str(self.duration))

    @staticmethod
    def win_command(*command):
        from ctypes import c_buffer, windll
        from sys import getfilesystemencoding
        buf = c_buffer(255)
        command = ' '.join(command).encode(getfilesystemencoding())
        errorCode = int(windll.winmm.mciSendStringA(command, buf, 254, 0))
        if errorCode:
            errorBuffer = c_buffer(255)
            windll.winmm.mciGetErrorStringA(errorCode, errorBuffer, 254)
            exceptionMessage = ('\n    Error ' + str(errorCode) + ' for command:'
                                                                  '\n        ' + command.decode() +
                                '\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
            raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
        return buf.value


class PygamePlayer(AudioPlayer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PygamePlayer, self).__init__()
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(48000, -16, 2, 1024)

    def __del__(self):
        pygame.mixer.quit()
        self.path = None
        print('deleted')

    def _load(self, path):
        frequency = int(self.meta_data['sample rate'])
        channels = int(self.meta_data['channels'])
        pygame.mixer.quit()
        pygame.mixer.init(frequency=frequency, channels=channels)
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(path)
        except pygame.error:
            self.signals.error.emit("Couldn't play this file!  It may be that it's corrupted.  "
                                    "Try downloading it again.")

    def _reload(self, path):
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(self.path)
        except pygame.error:
            self.signals.error.emit("Couldn't play this file!  It may be that it's corrupted.  "
                                    "Try downloading it again.")

    def _play(self):
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        except Exception as e:
            self.signals.error.emit(e)

    def _pause(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    def _resume(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

    def _stop(self):
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()

    def _goto(self, position):
        try:
            self._reload(self.path)
            pygame.mixer.music.play(start=round(position)/1000)
        except pygame.error:
            pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(position)


class AudioPlayerPlaceholder(AudioPlayer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AudioPlayerPlaceholder, self).__init__()
        self.passed_download_head = True

    @property
    def current_time(self):
        return self._current_time

    @current_time.setter
    def current_time(self, value):
        self._current_time = value

    @property
    def ended(self):
        return False

    def goto(self, position):
        self.current_time = position

    def preload(self, duration):
        self._duration = duration
        self.current_time = 0


def get_short_path_name(long_name):
    from ctypes import wintypes
    import ctypes
    _GetShortPathNameW = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetShortPathNameW
    _GetShortPathNameW.argtypes = [wintypes.LPCWSTR, wintypes.LPWSTR, wintypes.DWORD]
    _GetShortPathNameW.restype = wintypes.DWORD
    """
    Gets the short path name of a given long path.
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/23598461/200291
    """
    output_buf_size = 0
    while True:
        output_buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(output_buf_size)
        needed = _GetShortPathNameW(long_name, output_buf, output_buf_size)
        if output_buf_size >= needed:
            return output_buf.value
        else:
            output_buf_size = needed
```

**Test File**

```py
from AudioPlayer import SoundPlayer
import time
import os

file_name = "<file path>"
player = SoundPlayer()
player.load(file_name, 1)
player.audio_player.play()
time.sleep(5)
player.reload_sound_from_different_file(file_name)
time.sleep(2)
player.audio_player.stop()
player.reset()
time.sleep(1)
os.remove(file_name)
```

I know this is kinda a lot to ask but I've been stuck on this for like 3 days lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A [mcve] would make it much easier for folks to assist you with your problem. It could be some other process has your file open, you can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to search for a culprit. It might be something temporary, like a virus scanner, in which case you could add a delay or loop the deletion attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with windows security on an app at work a few weeks ago.  What ended up fixing it for me was to call the scripts from a batch file with the command prompt set to administrator.  If you want to try it, create a `.bat` file with:

```
cd path/to/your/script
python myscript.py
```

Then create a shortcut to the batch file and in the `properties` tab, select `advanced` then `run as administrator`.  This will run all of your scripts as administrator whenever the file is double clicked and managed to get me past those permission errors in my own case.  It might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the packages you installed may not be marked as trusted applications, that is the only other thing i would try other than giving the application administrator access temporarily by right clicking it, and clicking run as administrator.

To unblock the packages, navigate to `/python/lib/`, and look for the packages YOU installed (If any) or THE PACKAGES stated in the program. Right click on all the python files, and depending on the circumstances, it may show a box saying "Unblock this program" If so, check the box and click apply, then OK. I recommend doing this for every file in the package you are using.

If this doesn't work (Which there is a high probability it won't, as this is a unusual error), just tell me.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Even though this wasn't the issue I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out!  The problem s that pygame really doesn't like it when you quit the mixer more than once.  I had it quit every time I initialized a new player, for some reason it wouldn't fully release the file the second time.  What I ended up doing was to load the file to memory first then giving it to pygame that way, I could then delete it at my leisure :)