# FileNotFoundError on long pathname in Python in Windows

Tags: python

I have run into an issue while working with numpy's savetxt function. I have been trying to save data deep inside a file structure. Below is a minimal working example (for you to run it you will need to make the following directories, however).

```
import numpy as np

dir1 = "LongDirectoryName/"
dir2 = "VeryLongDirectoryName/"
dir3 = "EvenLongerDirectoryName/"
dir4 = "LongestOfThemAllDirectoryName/"

filename = "../" + dir1 + dir2 + dir3 + dir4 + "longfilename_with_129_charss.txt"   # this works
#filename = "../" + dir1 + dir2 + dir3 + dir4 + "longfilename_with_130_charsss.txt" # this does not 
print(len(filename))
myarray = np.array([1,2,3])
np.savetxt(filename, myarray)
```

The relative filepath is not an issue because the 129 character filename does work. It seems to me that 129 characters is the limit. When I go to try the 130 character filename, I receive the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\njkro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1359, in savetxt
    open(fname, 'wt').close()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../LongDirectoryName/VeryLongDirectoryName/EvenLongerDirectoryName/LongestOfThemAllDirectoryName/longfilename_with_130_charsss.txt'
```

Other Information
I am using Windows 10.
I am using Anaconda, and the version of numpy I am using is 1.16.2.

My questions:

1. Can anyone confirm this?
2. Is there an explanation for this character limit? I would understand a 128 character limit more than 129.
3. Is there a workaround (for long filenames) if I can't change the file system?

Comment: Works fine when I try it (and yes, I did use the commented-out version, not the "this works" version).

Comment: Is just the filename 130 char, or is it the whole path? The issue might be the length of the entire filepath being greater than Windows' MAX_PATH.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#:~:text=In%20the%20Windows%20API%20(with,and%20a%20terminating%20null%20character.

Comment: I answered; would you mind changing the title of your question to something like: "FileNotFoundError on long pathname in Python in Windows"? The error occurs at the `open()` function, so it doesn't have to do with numpy.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that Windows produces an error based on the absolute path. Even if you try to get into a deeply nested directory by `chdir`'ing in steps, it will fail if the absolute path is too long.

You can still get there by resorting to the FAT32-style 8-character filename aliases (even when on NTFS), for example, rather than

```
open('abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi/abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi', 'w')
```

you do

```
open('ABCDEF~1/ABCDEF~1', 'w')
```

but it is [rather involved to reliably get these short filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598289/how-to-get-windows-short-file-name-in-python).

Alternatively: change a registry setting to allow long path names on this particular Windows system (use `regedit.exe`): under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`, set `LongPathsEnabled` to DWORD value `1`.

Comment: Man, you're a genius! Thanks a lot! I would have spent hours finding that `LongPathsEnabled` flag by myself.